# Ruby 2.7.6 LoadError: cannot load such file -- ox/ox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I am trying to `bundle exec rails assets:precompile` in my project that depends on ox `2.10.0`. The issue seems to be that `ox` is unable to load its C extension for some reason. This is the line causing the problem https://github.com/ohler55/ox/blob/f060f84b5cadcff209de4a517e6289d1a39fe87d/lib/ox.rb#L79

After some investigation, I found that this may solve my problem https://github.com/ohler55/ox/pull/301/files

Due to dependencies, I cannot change my version of `2.10.0` and I can't really upgrade my ruby version from `2.7.6`. Is there anything that can be done to get around this?

Comment: Please include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). With Ruby 2.7.6, Rails 7.0.4, and a Gemfile with `gem 'ox', '2.10.0'`, the command `bundle exec rails assets:precompile` completes successfully. Likewise, [the examples in the README](https://github.com/ohler55/ox/blob/f060f84b5cadcff209de4a517e6289d1a39fe87d/README.md#object-dump-sample) from 2.10.0 complete successfully.

Comment: @anothermh I use the `ruby:2.7.6-slim-bullseye` docker image. What is causing the problem is when `ox` attempts to load the C extension. It seems this works fine for you, but I will keep digging.

Answer (score 0):

This build had been working fine for me. What changed was I removed `gem update --system` from my build. It had been installing `rubygems-update-3.3.26`, but had recently started installing `rubygems-update-3.4.4` which is what has apparently led to my issue. My problem was solved by removing the gem from my build.

Comment: Reading your answer literally, you're saying that 1) you removed `gem update --system` which 2) started forcing the installation of rubygems 3.4.4 instead of 3.3.26 which 3) caused the error mentioned in the original question and that 4) you resolved the problem by removing the gem ox entirely. Is that correct?